# Running gtest using ctest takes a lot of time to finish

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, ctest

I'm using cmake and gtest in my C++ project and TEST_DISCOVER_TESTS to add tests and run it witn ctest.

When I'm running the tests with ctest it takes a few minutes to finish but when I run the same tests using binary it takes only a few seconds.

As I understand ctest is running every test in separate process so it's like running binary again and again for each test.

Is there a way to run all the tests in one process, like running it with a binary?

Comment: so just `add_test(the_binary)`. Please show an [MCVE]

Comment: Also you can try gtest_add_tests https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html